# Insight debugger Compiler error with MSYS2-Mingw64

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2, insight

I have got the source files from insight-weekly-CVS-7.0.50-20091130. I have got the following errors. Thanks for your help.

```
config.status: executing bfd_stdint.h commands ./config.status: line 2602: cmp: command not found
config.status: executing default commands
mingw32-make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'info'.
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/insight-weekly-CVS-7.0.50-20091130/src/bfd/po'
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/insight-weekly-CVS-7.0.50-20091130/src/bfd'
mingw32-make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'info-am'.
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/insight-weekly-CVS-7.0.50-20091130/src/bfd'
mingw32-make[2]: *** [Makefile:1546: info-recursive] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/insight-weekly-CVS-7.0.50-20091130/src/bfd'## Heading ##
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile:3333: all-bfd] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/insight-weekly-//CVS-7.0.50-20091130/src'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:854: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you missing cmp.exe of diffutils? Try `pacman -S diffutils`

Comment: I have cmp.exe installed.

Comment: I wonder if anyone has a version of insight for PowerPC  target compiled for Windows 10 host and share it with me. Thanks.